# Exclude Terms from custom Taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type in which I have custom taxonomies setup.

I want to print out the categories(custom taxonomy) that a post is included in, but exclude one. I cannot find a solution to exclude the category though.
Here is my code to output a list of the categories the custom post type is filed under:

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'critter_cat', 'Critter Type: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
```

How do I exclude a specific category?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you used for registering the custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function in your functions.php file that calls `get_the_terms` to return the list of terms as an array and then remove the item you don't want.

Give this a try:

```
function get_excluded_terms( $id = 0, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '', $exclude = array() ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );

    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) )
        return $terms;

    if ( empty( $terms ) )
        return false;

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if(!in_array($term->term_id,$exclude)) {
            $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

            if ( is_wp_error( $link ) )
                return $link;

            $excluded_terms[] = '<a href="' . $link . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>';
            }
    }

    $excluded_terms = apply_filters( "term_links-$taxonomy", $excluded_terms );

    return $before . join( $sep, $excluded_terms ) . $after;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<?php echo get_excluded_terms( $post->ID, 'critter_cat', 'Critter Type: ', ', ', ' ', array(667)); ?>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I need sorry, maybe I wasn't clear above? Currently, my posts are displaying that they are in category(Custom taxonomy) A, B, C for example. But I would like to exclude A so it only displays B, C. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: So when you call `the_terms` it returns `A`, `B`, `C` and you want it to just return `B`, `C`?

Comment: Yes Robbie that's it, thanks. The ability to exclude a category(Custom Taxonomy) by ID or by name.

Comment: Yeah, i thought so... that is what this does... well, i can't test it, so i hope it does. How is it not working for you? Note, refesh your page, i've updated the answer a couple of times ;)

Comment: I've copied and pasted but nothing appears at all. I've added in the ID to the first line. Do I need to edit this line: 'unset($terms, $except); // <-- REMOVE THE ITEM YOU DON'T WANT' ? *Sorry been a loooong day! Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, don't change the `$id = 0`, that is just a default value for that parameter. The (only) bit you need to change is in the call to the function where i've put `'exclude_this'` you need to put the name of the category you want to exclude.

Comment: hmm, sorry i'll fire up a virtual machine later on when i have time and see what's wrong with it.

Comment: If you did that, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you Robbie.

Comment: @HuwRowlands I've updated the answer, try it out. I've changed how it filters the list of terms. You need to change the id in the array parameter `array(667)`. Set it to the id of the term you want to exclude. You can add a list of id's if you want `array(1,2,3)`. Hopefully this is what you need.

Comment: That's fantastic, it works! The terms don't link anymore though - is that a quick fix?

Comment: @HuwRowlands give it another try now.

Comment: You are a star. Thank you ever so much :)

Comment: no worries, i've not done any php or wordpress in a little while, so it was quite a good refresher for me :)

Comment: @Robbie Hi Robbie, I know this is a VERY old thread but is exactly what I need, however I have used your code above and it didn't work. The only difference is that instead of echo'ing the output, I have put a variable to it so I can do a foreach $terms as $term - would appreciate some help if you could spare a min please